# Which of these Java install locations do I use to set the Java_Home path?

Tags: linux-mint, java, openjdk

I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-b8aed675849f) to install Android Studio on my Linux Mint. I have reached the stage where I have to **set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the location of my JDK installation.**
I was offered this [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Your-Java_Home-Path-in-Ubuntu) to follow.
So far I have installed Java using this command:

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jre-headless -y

Next, I have used this command to see where Java is installed:

> locate openjdk

Which gives the following result:

[image]

In the [tutorial](https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Your-Java_Home-Path-in-Ubuntu), it says :

[image]
However, I do not have a path similar to the path shown in the tutorial:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64

I am trying to avoid unnecessary mistakes. So that's why I want to know which of the paths given by the ***locate openjdk*** should I use to set Java_Home path.

Answer (score 0):

By following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ajJpAdA_rY) (Only in the beginning), I have found the path.

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64

And then I continued with the original [tutorial](https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Your-Java_Home-Path-in-Ubuntu).

Hope this helps someone.